# Android Studio APK Analyzer Lombok Files

Tags: android-studio, android-proguard, lombok, android-studio-2.2

I am using the new APK Analyzer in Android Studio Preview 2.2 to examine my APK. I use lombok in my project. I am noticing in the resulting APK there are a lot of lombok files, including AUTHORS, changelog.txt, etc. It also includes a bunch of eclipse files, things I am not using, nor do I want. Specifically, I get a lot of InnerClasses warnings on these files when build and test. I have also had to enable multidex as what I believe is a result of all these extra items lombok pulls in. I believe a lot of this can be resolved with proguard. Does anyone have a working proguard to clean up the extra junk lombok is injecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need lombok `compileTime`. Changing your gradle file will fix your problems.